# what is the nearest or equivalent match to Pantone 289 in RAL or CMYK

Tags: color-conversion

We are looking at an equivalent for Pantone P 289 (Midnight Blue) on RAL or CMYK, please advise if this is known to someone.Thanks

Comment: you can convert color codes using internet searches: https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/289-C

Answer (score 2):

Pantone states the CMYK is `100 76 12 70`

[Pantone's page for 289](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/289-C)

Merely typing "Pantone 289 in RAL or CMYK" into a Google search presents the Pantone page above as the first result.

I'm unclear why you may feel that's not a valid breakout.